# How to see created database and table android studio flutter

Tags: flutter, android-studio, android-sqlite

I have created a database in flutter using SQFLite. I have created a table and inserted some values in it. I wanna see all those data and tables how to do that I am using android studio.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try it:

https://www.codaffection.com/flutter-article/view-sqlite-db-in-flutter-application/

Have a any issue?

Please Ask me.